# DaVinci resolve fails to load clips on Linux

Tags: linux, video, linux-mint, video-editing, video-encoding

I've just installed DaVinci resolve 16 on my Linux Mint 18 computer and cannot load any clips. They show up as -1 second long. I have tried .mkv, .mov, .mp4, .flv and a couple of other formats without any luck. Any idea what could be going on here?

System specs
i3 2130 @ 3.4GHz
GTX 1050
8GiB DDR3 RAM

EDIT: Yes the clips play back fine in the default video player.

EDIt 2: I have had no issues on Windows so I believe it is an issue with the Linux version.

EDIT 3: It appears to not be -1 seconds long, actually just *starting* from a negative timestamp. See image.

[image: Timestamp]

The actual length of the clip is around 9 and a half minutes.

EDIT: sorry for the bump but I really need a solution to this, and it's been 16 days.

Comment: NVIDIA drivers and codecs are properly installed?

Comment: Yes, version 384.130-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (from "driver manager") which is the latest shown version.

Answer (score 0):

I found that on Linux Mint that Resolve will load a mov file.

You can convert to mov using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
    -c:v dnxhd -profile:v dnxhr_hq -format yuvj422p \
    -c:a pcm_s16le \
    -f mov output.mov
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).